# Incorporating error and exception handling into my python script

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I'm attempting to incorporate error handling into my python script.

prod.py searches the kernel config file for a module and returns it's branch.

example:

**comp@able~$** python prod.py CRYPTO_DEV 
# Random Number Generation

```
import sys

module = sys.argv[1]

def probe(module): 
  with open('/usr/src/linux/.config', 'r') as module_list:
    modlist = module_list.read()
    blocks = modlist.split('\n\n')
    block = filter (lambda search:module in search, blocks)

    for line in block:
      head = line.split('\n')
      print head[1]
      break

probe(module)
```

I'd like to capture typos and print "Are you sure that is a module?" in return.

End Question

### <strike>The errors  below were thrown by shell, and not python. Apologies.</strike>

but I would also like to handle errors like;

**comp@able~$** ./prod.py CRYPTO_DEV;[ 
# Random Number Generation 
bash:[:missing `]

**comp@able~$** ./prod.py CRYPTO_DEV( 
# Random Number Generation
bash:syntax error near unexpected token `('

---

I attempted some variations of 'try:' and 'except', but either broke the script, returned no value, or returned a value regardless of error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two error cases you've given are nothing to do with Python. They are errors from your shell telling you that it doesn't understand what you are asking it to do - your python script hasn't started running yet.

Comment: Apologies, understood.

Comment: You may want to read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html and follow the examples therein, or show us your `try/except` additions that don't work.